# Appspot.com API from swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I'm developing an iOS app that translates Japanese sentences to English using Google Translate API.
I could fetch translated data from the API using `curl` command, but am now having a trouble to fetch data using Swift.

Following is the `curl` command I used.

```
curl -X POST \
>   https://XXXXX.appspot.com/api/translate \
>   -H 'Postman-Token: XXXXX' \
>   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
>   -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----XXXXX' \
>   -F 'text=私はあなたが好きです。' \
>   -F target_lang=en \
>   -F text_lang=ja
```

However, following swift code just has `nil` in `result`.

```
        let reqB: [String:Any] = ["text": text, "target_lang": "en", "text_lang": "ja"]
        let reqBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reqB)
        guard let reqUrl = URL(string: "https://XXXXX.appspot.com/api/translate") else {
            return
        }

        var req = URLRequest(url: reqUrl)
        req.httpMethod = "POST"
        req.httpBody = reqBody
        req.setValue("XXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Postman-Token")
        req.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "cache-control")
        req.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=----XXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {
            (data , response ,error) in
            session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you mean the `response` of the `dataTask` is `nil`? Have you checked if there is an `error` returned?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by Alamofire4.
It seems "multipartFormData" is the key of this problem.

```
    let reqUrl = "XXX"
    let originalText = sendingText.data(using: .utf8)!
    let targetLang = "en".data(using: .utf8)!
    let textLang = "ja".data(using: .utf8)!

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(originalText, withName: "text", mimeType: "text/plain")
            multipartFormData.append(targetLang, withName: "target_lang", mimeType: "text/plain")
            multipartFormData.append(textLang, withName: "text_lang", mimeType: "text/plain")
    }, to: reqUrl) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if !response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("# ERROR")
                } else {
                    print("# SUCCESS")
                    if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let translatedText = json["translated_text"] as? String {
                        print(translatedText)

                }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```